# How to alter prettyPhoto description HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i want to modify the "description html" of the prettyPhoto i dont think there is a callback available when prettoPhoto lightbox is "shown" (but a callback for close exist)

what do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, there is:

```
changepicturecallback: function(){}, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
```

As long as that fires when the first picture is shown, you could create a function to check a globally available variable and do your magic on startup, set the `pretty_opened` variable (or whatever you want to call it) to true, then use the callback to set it to false on close.

Comment: is it called when the picture is loaded the first time too?